# How to change the order of the Windows titlebar buttons when moved over to the left

Tags: 20.04, titlebar, window-buttons, gnome-flashback, orientation

Using Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome Session Flashback, I got accustomed to the title bar icons being on the left. I've found that I prefer the 'close' button to be closest and within reach for quick access, then the 'minimize' button where the 'maximize' button is furthest away; being that by double clicking title bar toggles maximize anyways.

I've tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu:maximize,minimize,close'
```

Which results in the orientation of the title bar buttons switched back over to the right. "Gnome Tweak Tool" still shows it on the left.

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The colon (`:`) is the separator for left and right.

For example:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'appmenu,maximize,minimize,close:'
```

[image]

Comment: Pew, pew! Thanks so much! That did the trick. Archived and luv'n linux!